# VisualStudio 2017: Find where a code snippet is coming from

Tags: visual-studio, c#, snippets

I have a few extensions, and seems like one of them introduced a code snippet that is really annoying.

[image: The snippet]

I use `prop` for making properties a lot, but now it also suggests this `public readobly object p;` as the first selection, which I do not want.

I went through all the snippets in both VS snippet manager and ReSharper snippet manager and couldn't find it. Even did a string search for `readonly` in all the snippet files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033`, but couldn't find anything resembling it.

I also tried disabling some extensions. But still to no avail.
It is driving me insane.

How do I disable it?

PS: Here's all the extensions I have installed:
[image: Extensions1]
[image: Extenions2]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here within about a week I'd be tempted to flag your question and request it be migrated to StackOverflow as they have developers there who use VS almost every day

Comment: Thanks, I could also cross post it there, but seems likes it would be off topic for that forum.

Comment: You need to disable all your add-ons to determine if the snippets are a default feature or a feature of one of your add-one specifically Resharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove or disable the jetbrains ReShaper

Comment: ok seems like disabling r# removes it, so I'll try to find it in resharpers settings

Comment: It was ZenSharp https://github.com/ulex/ZenSharp it doesn't get added to the snippet list